# How to avoid calling fopen() with a buffer that is not null-terminated in C?

Tags: c, string, null, fopen, stdio

Let's look at this example:

```
static FILE *open_file(const char *file_path)
{
    char buf[80];
    size_t n = snprintf(buf, sizeof (buf), "%s", file_path);
    assert(n < sizeof (buf));
    return fopen(buf, "r");
}
```

Here, the `assert()` is off-by-one. From the manpage for `snprintf`:

"Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings)."

So, if it returns 80, then the string will fill the buffer, and won't be terminated by \0. This will cause a problem because `fopen()` assumes it is null terminated.

What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: `assert (n < (sizeof(buf)-1));` ??

Comment: I don't see your problem, if it returns 80 your assert triggers because `80 < 80` is false.

Comment: The statement “the `assert()` is off-by-one” in the question appears to be false. If the length of `file_path` is less than `sizeof buf`, then all of its characters will be successfully written to `buf`, with a terminating null byte, and the code will work as desired. If the length of `file_path` is greater than or equal to `sizeof buf`, then not all of its characters will be written to `buf`, as `snprintf` will have to stop early to leave room for the terminating null byte. In this case, the `assert` correctly catches the problem. Its test appears to be exactly correct, not off by one.

Comment: This code appears to have no purpose in copying `file_path` into `buf`. The entire body of the function could be replaced with `return fopen(file_path, "r");`, and then it would not have any risk of truncating the file path due to the size of `buf`.

Comment: dasblinkenlight suggests that, in your actual code, you are not using `snprintf` with `%s` but are using `snprintf` with a more complicated format string, such as `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,  "%s/%s.%s", StartDirectory, file_path, Extension);`, to give a hypothetical example. If so, you ought to show the actual code, or at least sample code closer to it, so that more appropriate advice can be given.

Comment: Assuming the situation is as described in the above comment, a typical solution is to find the size required by executing `size_t n = snprintf(NULL, 0, pattern, arguments…);`, then allocate memory with `char *buf = malloc(n + 1);`, then test `buf` to guard against `malloc` failing, then fill the buffer with `snprintf(buf, n+1, pattern, arguments…);`, then perform the `fopen`, then free `buf`, then return the result of `fopen`.

Comment: *What is the best way to prevent this*?   easy.  replace all the contents of the function with: `return fopen( file_path, "r" );`  Note: the "r" is if you want to read the file.  To write and want to keep the prior contents use: "a".  If you want to create the file or throw away any prior contents use: "w".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, if it returns 80, then the string will fill the buffer, and won't be terminated by `\0`

That is incorrect: the string would be null-terminated no matter what you pass for `file_path`. Obviously, the string would be cut off at the `sizeof(buf)-1`.

Note that `snprintf` could return a number above 80 as well. This would mean that the string you wanted to print was longer than the buffer you have provided.

> What is the best way to prevent this?

You are already doing it: the `assert` is not necessary for preventing unterminated strings. You can use the return value to decide if any truncation has happened, and pass a larger buffer to compensate:

```
// Figure out the size
size_t n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", file_path);
// Allocate the buffer and print into it
char *tmpBuf = malloc(n+1);
snprintf(tmpBuf, n+1, "%s", file_path);
// Prepare the file to return
FILE *res = fopen(tmpBuf, "r");
// Free the temporary buffer
free(tmpBuf);
return res;
```

Comment: OP’s question and code do not really make any sense. Your new code shows them how to copy a string of arbitrary length into a temporary buffer, but what is the point of that? The code `return fopen(file_path, "r");` would accomplish the same result better.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's absolutely true. My assumption here is that OP's real code uses a more complex format string, with more data to print. Otherwise there's no point in going through this whole exercise with `snprintf`.

Comment: If that assumption is the case, then we ought to show OP how to use `snprintf(NULL, 0,…);`, then `malloc`, then `snprintf(buffer,…)`, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way to prevent this?

Simple, don't give it a non-null terminated string. Academic questions aside, you are in control of the code you write. You don't have to protect against yourself sabotaging the project in every conceivable way, you just have to not sabotage yourself.

If everyone checked and double checked everything in code, the performance loss would be incredible. There's a reason why `fopen` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here.

First `assert()` is used to catch issues as a part of designer testing. It is not meant to be used in production code.

Secondly if the file path is not complete then do you really want to call `fopen()`?

Normally what is done is to add one to the expected number of characters.

```
static FILE *open_file(const char *file_path)
{
    char buf[80 + 1] = {0};

    size_t n = snprintf(buf, 80, "%s", file_path);
    assert(n < sizeof (buf));
    return fopen(buf, "r");
}
```

Comment: This code is wasteful. `snprintf` writes a terminating null byte, so there is no need to initialize `buf` with a null byte. And `char buf[80 + 1] = {0};` initializes the entirety of it, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you had pointed out that the code indicates an incomplete understanding of the `snprintf()` function then I would agree with you. Saying it is wasteful is a moral judgement that is really in the eye of the beholder. I would submit that any waste from an extra character and initializing an array of `char` to zero pales in comparison to the performance hit from opening a file.

Comment: It's not a moral judgment, it's just *ridiculously pedantic*... It is far better to initialize `buf` than not. There is nothing inefficient about it. If `buf` was `buf[800000]` -- then the comment may make more sense, but `buf[80]`?? Really?